# Long-press on item message to change layout

Tags: android

[Long press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAM4I.png)

When I long-click on an item of the message, the item will display and the layout changes like the picture. I want to make this , but i don't have a keyword to find this solution. I need a keyword or some example to make it.

Comment: I think you are looking for popuomenu https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways you can do. I am going to share one example.

Implement View.OnLongClickListener as follows

```
private void setupLongPress() {
  imageButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v){
            // here your staff
            // we added dialog method here as follows
            createPreviewDialog();
            return false;
        }
   });
}
```

Now use LayoutInflater to inflate new layout as a popup windows

```
private Dialog createPreviewDialog() {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_preview, null);
    LinearLayout closeButton = view.findViewById(R.id.close);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener (){
        @Override
        public void onClick ( View view ) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    View okButton = view.findViewById(R.id.ok);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dismiss();
            // here your staff
        }
    });

    builder.setView(view);
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: nice answer , but i want to set alpha = 0.5 for all layout and set alpha = 1 for item chat in a recyclerview, should i usepopup windown :?